# GCP - Failed to update metadata for Cloud SQL instance

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I'm receiving the below response from the App which is running on GKE. 
Please advise.
This was working fine until yesterday.

==========================================================================
Cloud SQL SSL Setting - Unsecured connections are allowed to connect to this instance.

```
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://google/<DB-NAME>?cloudSqlInstance=<INSTANCE-CONN- 
    URL>&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&user=<USER>&password=<PASS>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-socket-factory</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.15</version>
        </dependency>


Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
```

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Throwables.throwIfUnchecked(Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V

I 2019-09-22T08:01:28.370430889Z    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:150)

I 2019-09-22T08:01:28.370424094Z }

I 2019-09-22T08:01:28.370417350Z   "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED"

I 2019-09-22T08:01:28.370409799Z   "message" : "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",

I 2019-09-22T08:01:28.370402379Z   } ],

I 2019-09-22T08:01:28.370378956Z     "reason" : "forbidden"

I 2019-09-22T08:01:28.370371540Z     "message" : "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",

I 2019-09-22T08:01:28.370364751Z     "domain" : "global",

I 2019-09-22T08:01:28.370358271Z   "errors" : [ {

I 2019-09-22T08:01:28.370351106Z   "code" : 403,

I 2019-09-22T08:01:28.370344017Z {

I 2019-09-22T08:01:28.370207921Z java.lang.RuntimeException: [test:production] **Failed to update metadata for Cloud SQL instance.**
    at com.google.cloud.sql.core.CloudSqlInstance.addExceptionContext(CloudSqlInstance.java:474)
    at com.google.cloud.sql.core.CloudSqlInstance.fetchMetadata(CloudSqlInstance.java:315)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are running into an authentication problem:

> "message" : "Request had insufficient authentication scopes."

Verify that the service account being used to the the Cloud SQL instance has the following IAM roles:

- `Cloud SQL Client` (preferred)
- `Cloud SQL Editor`
- `Cloud SQL Admin`

OR at least the following IAM permissions:

- `cloudsql.instances.connect`
- `cloudsql.instances.get`

(These two permissions are also in the `Cloud Client` role)

Answer (score 1):

Towards the end of your spring data source url add `useSSL=false`

E.g.
 `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://some-ip-address:some-port/Dbname?useSSL=false`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No luck yet. Still i'm getting the same.

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://google/<DB>?verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=false&requireSSL=false&cloudSqlInstance=test:us-central1:prod&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory&user=<USER>&password=<PASS>

Comment: You mentioned the app worked fine till yesterday. Has anything changed since then in the environment such as IP Addresses? Also are you able to connect to the Cloud sql instance from  command prompt? Please also check the cloud sql instance console and see if anything has changed especially in the CONNECTIONS -> Authorized Network section and USERS section?

Comment: Also notice some difference in your datasource configuration compared to what I have seen. Can you try this form? spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://<IP Address>:<Port>/<Schema>?useSSL=false spring.datasource.username=<user> spring.datasource.password=<pass>